# What is the difference between $P(D|\theta)$ and $P(\theta|D)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading this: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/Joint_MLE_MAP.pdf

I found it extremely useful. However, I am a bit confused about the difference between $P(D|\theta)$ and $P(\theta|D)$.

The document first declares D as a sequence of $n$ consecutive coin tosses each of which is independent of each other and $\theta$ is the probability of, say, heads, that we are trying to predict. (For example, D=1010001001)

Then, it says Maximum Likelihood Estimation (**MLE**) defines $\theta$ by,

$$
\theta^{\mathrm{MLE}} = \underset{\theta} {\mathrm{argmax}} ~ P(D~|~\theta).
$$

If we see $\alpha_0$ heads and $\alpha_1$ tails in D ($\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 = n$), we should maximize,

$$
\theta^{\alpha_0}. (1-\theta)^{\alpha_1}
$$

Then, document uses derivation of this and sets it to $0$ to find which $\theta$ maximizes that quantity. Until this point everything is clear on my mind.

Then, it switches to Maximum a Posteriori Probability Estimation (**MAP**). And it says we should maximize $P(\theta~|~D)$ for MAP, which is,

$$
\theta^{\mathrm{MAP}} = \underset{\theta} {\mathrm{argmax}} ~ P(\theta~|~D).
$$

and it uses Bayes formula to translate $P(\theta~|~D)$ to $P(D~|~\theta)$. In the process of conversion $P(\theta~|~D)$ to $P(D~|~\theta)$, we also get $P(D)$ and $P(\theta)$,

$$
\theta^{\mathrm{MAP}} = \underset{\theta} {\mathrm{argmax}} ~ P(\theta~|~D) = \underset{\theta} {\mathrm{argmax}} ~ \frac{ P(D~|~\theta) P(\theta) }{P(D)}.
$$

My questions are:

1. I can understand $P(D~|~\theta) = \theta^{\alpha_0}. (1-\theta)^{\alpha_1}$ in this example. However, I am having hard time to grasp what does $P(\theta~|~D)$ mean conceptually in this example.
2. What does $P(\theta)$ and $P(D)$ mean in the last equation in this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above say that you believe that $\theta$ lies somewhere between $0 and 1$ but you have no reason to favor one value over the other (before observing outcomes).  Then you can start with the assumption that $\theta$ is a uniform random variable on $[0, 1]$.

1. $P(\theta | D)$ means: if you now observe the outcome $D$, what is the probability that $D$ was chosen from the distribution with parameter $\theta$.
2. $P(\theta)$ is given by the uniform distribution (by assumption) and you can calculate $P(D)$ by:
     $$P(D) = \int_0^1 P(D | \theta) d\theta$$
   That quantity is the probability you observe $D$ given your assumption on the distribution of $\theta$.